# Manage multiple world files in gentoo linux for different machines

Tags: linux, gentoo

If a user selects a package to be installed gentoo adds it to `/var/lib/portage/world`.
Hence it can be used to install the same software on many systems by copying this file and run
`# emerge -uDN world` afterwards.

How can I manage a set of packages that should be installed on all machines (setA) and
another set of packages which should only go to the local machine (setB)?

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/portage/sets/*` and `/var/lib/portage/world_sets` can be used to accomplish this.

Read more about it in `man portage`.

Comment: will I have to create 
`/etc/portage/sets/mynetbook` and `/etc/portage/sets/myofficepc` and add `@mynetbook` to `/var/lib/portage/world_sets` and then share `/etc/portage/sets/*` on all machines?

Comment: and how will I install new software then? `emerge foo` would change the worldfile, but I want to sort foo to `/etc/portage/sets/basesystem`

Comment: Yes, you can do it that way. To install new software, you need to adjust the set file and emerge @world. Note that this only upgrades when you specify -u and only rebuilds based on USE flags if you specify -N, therefore if you don't specify these two options you can use it to just emerge a new package. You may be able to more easily accomplish things by writing some bash functions in your .bash_profile that manipulate these files for you.